Worst case timing analysis for Setup and Hold time of a FF
Image Source: DDCA
For Setup analysis, following waveform configuration is used:

For Hold analysis, following waveform configuration is used:
My question is: why the waveform below is not used for setup? Isn't this the worst case (shortest) timespan available between launch and latch edge?


The setup time is for adjacent clock edges. Hold time is for concurrent clock edges.

In the image 2, ideally both clock edges are concurrent, but because of slight skew, would they still remain concurrent? Setup analysis not needed for concurrent? any strong reasons for that?

For setup time, the worst case is when the next clock edge of R2 happens sooner relative to R1, so the data does not have enough time before the clock. For the hold time, the worst case is when the clock edge of R2 happens later and the same edge of R1 happens later. Then, the data will not hold enough after the clock edge of R2 and will update sooner.

Setup Time
It is defined as the amount of time the data needs to be stable before the clock edge. The worst case for that scenario is when the data arrives less than \$t_{\text{setup}}\$ before the next clock edge of R\$_2\$. When does that happen?

The clock of R\$_1\$ arrives late, pushing the data arrival time for R\$_2\$ towards right.
The clock of R\$_2\$ arrives early, pushing the latest acceptable data arrival time for R\$_2\$ towards left.

Both of these effects squeeze the maximum available logic delay.
